# Запретить блоку прерыватся

Tags: javascript, css

Имею дело с многоколоночной версткой через `multiple-column`.
Проблема заключается в том что я не хочу, чтобы блок (`div`) разорвало на границах .
Хочу чтобы выполнялось условие:если блок не помещается целиком - переводим его на новую строку .
Тестовий пример

```
  <style>
    *{padding:0;margin:0;}
    #parent{width:300px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;
      column-count:3;-moz-column-count:3
    }
    #parent p{background:red;margin-bottom:3px;

      /* white-space:nowrap;*/

    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="parent" >

    <p>one</p>
    <p>this text must view in 1 block! 
    this text must v
    </p>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>one</p>

  </div>
```

Код http://jsbin.com/AJOCeci/2/edit

Comment: @SverxnovA, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. (пример кода)

Comment: а у меня и мысли нету получить готовый результат....

Comment: так продемонстрируйте вашу проблему

Comment: в webkit(chrome) оно видимо работает как вам нужно ? http://jsbin.com/AJOCeci/3/

Comment: нет.У тебя просто получился удачный тестовый пример.Логику которую я пытаюсь получить ты уловил.